# not having to load a dataset over and over

Tags: python, global-variables, spyder

Currently in R, once you load a dataset (for example with read.csv), Rstudio saves it as a variable in the global environment. This ensures you don't have to load the dataset every single time you do a particular test or change.

With Python, I do not know which text editor/IDE will allow me to do this. E.G - I want to load a dataset once, and then subsequently do all sorts of things with it, instead of having to load it every time I run the script.

Any points as to how to do this would be very useful

Comment: You've already tagged an IDE that provides this functionality :) The underlying implementation is termed IPython, which is in an interactive console in Spyder. Equally, you can read a file in once and then hash that code out in subsequent runs, and you'll still access the data from the first run

Answer (score 0):

It depends how large your data set is.

For relatively smaller datasets you could look at installing Anaconda Python Jupyter notebooks. Really great for working with data and visualisation once the dataset is loaded. For larger datasets you can write some functions / generators to iterate efficiently through the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The RStudio process actually does reload the data when you restart the
workspace, but it does it automatically for you when you re-open the workspace.
So when you say you want something similar in Python I assume you mean that
you don't want to re-type the code to read the data every time, but you want
some automatic way to reload the data.

You can accomplish this using Jupyter notebooks by

- create a notebook
- put code to load your data into the first cell
- save the notebook

Then later

- open the notebook you saved
- run the first cell to automatically load the data

If you want to do a lot of different things with the same
data you can make copies of the notebook that loads the data
and use the first cell to load the data in all cases.  If you
do this too much you probably should make a module helper and
import the helper...

For example this notebook:

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_doodle/blob/master/notebooks/State%20outlines.ipynb

Loads and parses and XML file and then creates some derivative
data structures using the xml data.  Since it is stored in a notebook
I never need to type the load logic again -- I can just rerun the cell to
load the data.